# PHP - Get variable of another function in a php controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making the hangman game. Can somebody help me? I want to use the $arrayOfWords in 2 functions but how can I get a word of that array of the cuntion getWord into postLetter? So when I open the page it should pick a random word but that word will be dissapeared.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GalgjeController extends Controller
{

    private $arrayOfWords;

    public function getWord() {
        $arrayOfWords = [
            'banaan' => 'Het is geel',
            'appel' => 'Het is rood',
            'peer' => 'Het is groen',
            'auto' => 'Het heeft 4 wielen',
            'fietsband' => 'Nederland staat hier bekend om',
            'telefoon' => 'Wat alle mensen tegenwoordig tebruiken',
            'laptop' => 'Hier wordt op getypt',
            'televisie' => 'Hier kijk je vaak naar',
            'kip' => 'Leeft op een boerderij',
            'poes' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
            'kat' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
            'hond' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
            'varken' => 'Leeft op de boerderij',
            'luipaard' => 'Grote versie van een kat',
            'bliksem' => 'Is super snel en geeft licht',
            'onweer' => 'Maakt hard lawaai',
            'regen' => 'Dit gebeurt vaak in Nederland buiten',
            'weer' => 'Wordt al meer als 30 jaar in de gaten gehouden',
            'school' => 'Waar je nu of vroeger veel dagelijks naar toe gaat',
            'opleiding' => 'Wat je studeert noem je een...',
        ];
    }
    public function postLetter(Request $request)
    {
        {
            $arrayOfWords = $this->getWord();

            $result = [''];


            $letterInput = $request->input('letter');

            foreach ($arrayOfWords as $word => $tip) {
                $chosenWord = array_rand($arrayOfWords, 1);
                foreach (str_split($chosenWord) as $char) {
                    if (in_array($char, $letterInput)) {
                        array_push($result, $letterInput);
                        print_r($result);
                    } else {
                        print_r($result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a class PROPERTY already setup called `$arrayOfWords` so change `$arrayOfWords = [` to `$this->arrayOfWords = [` and use `$this->arrayOfWords ` in all the other code.

Comment: As you have what looks like a class here, why not just add the array as a constant?

Comment: return $arrayOfWords from getWord();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
public function getWords() {
        $arrayOfWords = [
```

with

```
public function getWords() {
return [
```

this way `arrayOfWords` from

```
            $arrayOfWords = $this->getWord();
```

will actually hold the array

Answer (score 0):

You should return the array inside your getWords() function.

For example

```
function getExampleArray()
{
    $arr = [1, 2, 3];
    return $arr;
}
```

Or even easier:

```
function getExampleArray()
{
    return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want access same array in multiple function.

So you can create a new `setting.php` file in your `config` folder and just put below code in it.

```
 <?php

 return [
        'banaan' => 'Het is geel',
        'appel' => 'Het is rood',
        'peer' => 'Het is groen',
        'auto' => 'Het heeft 4 wielen',
        'fietsband' => 'Nederland staat hier bekend om',
        'telefoon' => 'Wat alle mensen tegenwoordig tebruiken',
        'laptop' => 'Hier wordt op getypt',
        'televisie' => 'Hier kijk je vaak naar',
        'kip' => 'Leeft op een boerderij',
        'poes' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
        'kat' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
        'hond' => 'Hebben mensen als huisdier',
        'varken' => 'Leeft op de boerderij',
        'luipaard' => 'Grote versie van een kat',
        'bliksem' => 'Is super snel en geeft licht',
        'onweer' => 'Maakt hard lawaai',
        'regen' => 'Dit gebeurt vaak in Nederland buiten',
        'weer' => 'Wordt al meer als 30 jaar in de gaten gehouden',
        'school' => 'Waar je nu of vroeger veel dagelijks naar toe gaat',
        'opleiding' => 'Wat je studeert noem je een...', 
];
```

Then  you can access this using `config('setting');` line.

```
 $arrayOfWords = config('setting');
```

`setting.php` is just reference name you can have any name for file.